# DI,Service Name Conventions.why not has viewCache?

Tags: php, phalcon

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.6.0/reference/di.html

in public/index.php, codeing :

```
$di->set('viewCache', function(){

    //Cache data for one day by default
    $frontCache = new Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Output(array(
            "lifetime" => 86400
    ));

    //Memcached connection settings
    $cache = new Phalcon\Cache\Backend\File($frontCache, array(
            "cacheDir" => "../apps/caches/"
    ));

    return $cache;
});
```

that,in controller,i can use this->view->cache(), why not viewCache not in service name conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service `viewCache` can be accessed like this:

```
// In controller
$this->view->cache();
```

or

```
// In controller 
$this->di->get('viewCache');
```

or

```
// In a module or other file
$di = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault();
$di->get('viewCache');
```

Comment: i mean viewCache why not in that url document table list?
i know how to use

Comment: Because it is the name of the service. `viewCache` refers to the `view` component and the `cache` on that. It is a naming convention used in the framework to distinguish keys in the service container.